# set header into "Send it to the Server" request

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, file-browser

I faced an issue with the Request which "Send it to the Server" button makes. I need to set header into this request.

How can I do that from front end side?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answer my own question.*

Every dialog could be modified by listening to `dialogDefinition` event.
https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR-event-dialogDefinition

Comment: Please add more explanation about your answer and avoid relying totally on an off-site resource.